# path resolution errors in typescript when in production

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, heroku

i have been working on a typescript based express API, when in local development, there is absouletely no issue of import errors with typescript. Import errros arise when I try to deploy this to `heroku` and build the project the following relative path errors arise.

`src/main.ts(9,28): error TS2307: Cannot find module './routes/FileOps' or its corresponding type declarations. src/routes/fileOps.ts(2,26): error TS2307: Cannot find module '../controllers/FileOps' or its corresponding type declarations.`

My `tsconfig.json` is as follows:

`

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": ["dom", "es6", "es2017", "esnext.asynciterable"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "removeComments": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "baseUrl": "."
},
"exclude": ["node_modules"],
"include": ["./src/**/*.tsx", "./src/**/*.ts"]
```

`

My build script is as follows:
`"build": "yarn clean && prettier --write src/ && tsc && gulp postbuild",`

Can someone please help me understand the best way to understand a viable option for path resolution here
as `tsc` is failing here when i try to deploy this to heroku.

Comment: `src/routes/fileOps.ts` This will not work. The path needs to be relative. starting like this `../../routes/fileOps.ts` the number of `../` depends on how many folders behind you want to navigate. If you are using vscode I suggest adding an extension call `path intellisense` which is very helpful.

Comment: @MarcusMelodious my import statements look like the following `import { FileRouter } from './routes/fileOps';
import { FetchRouter } from './routes/FetchFile';
import { DownloadRouter } from './routes/Downloads';
`, these are exactly as recommended by the `path-intellisense`

Comment: ok then. Try building the project on local machine. And deploy the production build from local machine. If its working on local machine, then the issue is with heroku deployment. Which can be difficult to figure out. Their documentation isn't the best. I once had issues with Heroku. The problem was that my package.json wasn't in the root folder and inside the server folder.

Comment: Also, have a look at how the build folder structure is setup. Sometimes, the build can add or remove the src folder. Moving the import requirements one folder above or below.

Comment: @MarcusMelodious yes I will try building locally and deploy the production build, meanwhile I hope someone has a fix for why this might be happening because that error messasge only shows up in the heroki build logs, not locally,